# How to decide maximum lags length in Newey West T stats

Tags: time-series, neweywest

wI have a time series data. I run Newey-West statistics on it without mentioning lag length. It accepts null hypothesis. On the same time series when I mention max.length=50. It rejected null hypothesis. My data consists of 192 observations. Please tell me whether i should mention max. lag or go by default option.

Comment: @JesperHybel I can share with you data

Comment: No thx. But you can edit the question to include minimal reproducible example. You can use dput() for data or make code that simulates.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example